# Settings.settings - How do I change from one environment to another?

Tags: c#, dll, settings, appsettings, application-settings

I have a Web App Project (compiled DLL) along with 3 DLL projects.  In my DLL projects I am using the Properties/Setting.settings to extract mutable settings from the DLL.  However, when I publish from environment to the next I have not figured how to change the Settings.settings values for the new environment.  It appears that the settings.settings values are stored in the [project root]/app.settings file.  However, when a DLL project compiles it does *NOT* create a [project name].config file for deployment.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the settings.settings in the DLL and moved everything to a custom config section in my web.config.  Everything is up and running and all of my dependencies were not broken.